# how to set custom tabhost style without TabActivity

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I set tab without TabActivity,
so my tabHost always has an error.
please tell me how to do.
thanks.

```
private void setupTab(Class<?> ccls, String name, String label,
        Integer iconId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ccls);

    View tab = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView text = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.text);
    if (iconId != null) {
        image.setImageResource(iconId);
    }
    text.setText(label);

    TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(name).setIndicator(tab)
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

i read [Android Tab-Host](http://www.dotblogs.com.tw/alonstar/archive/2012/04/18/android_tabhost.aspx#58249)
to earn

Comment: print you logcat what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

It can't build.
i'm run error by tabHost cannot be resolved.